# Не блокируются IP в iptables

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

Добрый день. Вообщем, пытаюсь заблокировать несколько IP спамеров, чтобы не заходили на сайт и сервер. Для проверки что все работает добавил также свой IP.
В итоге после сохранения командой service iptables save и перезагрузки сервера могу как и раньше заходить на сайт, а также логиниться на сервер через ssh.

Вот как выглядит файл /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Thu Dec  8 18:42:17 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [41131:31130358]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 31915 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 51915 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -s 46.161.9.8/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -s 185.121.190.12/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -s 41.57.116.0/24 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -s 41.57.117.0/24 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Dec  8 18:42:17 2016
```

Команда systemctl status iptables выдаёт, что iptables запущен и работает

```
# systemctl status iptables
● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2016-12-08 18:38:34 CET; 4min 6s ago
  Process: 764 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/iptables/iptables.init start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 764 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/iptables.service
```

А вот вывод команды iptables -vnL

```
# iptables -vnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
95808   10M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    1    32 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  116 11037 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
50006 3899K ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
   46  2740 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW udp dpt:53
11343  649K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    2   104 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:31915
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:51915
  495 26375 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       46.161.9.8           0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       185.121.190.12       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       41.57.116.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       41.57.117.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 156K packets, 116M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Тем не менее мой IP не блокируется, подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть причина.
Сервер CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core), работаю под root-ом

Comment: Пробывали постаивть запрещающие правила выше остальных?

Comment: Аналогичная проблема! Нашли решение?